# How to find a function that minimize the following expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume $ X $ is a continuous random variable which have a density function.
Assume $ \underline{Y} $ is a random vector which also have a density function.
And finally assume we have a joint density function of the random variable and the random vector.

How can I find a function $\phi$, such that $ \mathbb{E}\left[\left|X-\phi\left(\underline{Y}\right)\right||\underline{Y}\right] $ would be minimal?

I'm not sure where to start. I do know that the asnwer should be that $\phi(\underline{Y})$ should be a median of $F_{X|\underline{Y}}$, but Im not sure how to prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed $y$,
\begin{align}
\int |x-m| f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\, dx&=\int_{-\infty}^{m}(m-x)f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\, dx \\
&\quad+\int_{m}^{\infty}(x-m)f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\, dx.
\end{align}
Differentiating the RHS w.r.t. $m$ and equating to zero yields
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{m^*}f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\, dx=\int_{m^*}^{\infty}f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\, dx,
$$
or
$$
F_{X\mid Y}(m^*\mid y)=1-F_{X\mid Y}(m^*\mid y).
$$
That is $m^*$ is the conditional median of $X$ given $Y$.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you did, you used Leibnitz rule to differentiate this integral. But, $m$ is a function of $ y$ and so is $ f_{X|Y}\left(x|y\right) $, so why dont you differentiate $ f_{X|Y}\left(x|y\right) $ also as a part of Leibnitz rule?

Comment: @FreeZe When we condition on $\{Y=y\}$, $\phi(y)$ is just a number. We are trying to find its optimal value.

Comment: And yet, you do differentiate $m$ and do not differentiate $f_{X|Y}(x) $ although they both can be seen as just numbers

Comment: We want to find an optimal $m$ when $y$ is fixed. So, we differentiate w.r.t. $m$. Why would one differentiate $f_{X|Y}(x\mid y)$?